# How to create a .bat file that allows me to enter an input (or even better, get the input from the clipboard)?

Tags: windows, batch-file, video, cmd, youtube

I download videos from youtube (and other sites) through youtube-dl.exe by writing a command on .cmd. I managed to create a .bat file with a command that allows me to download a specific playlist of my youtube channel with a double click. What I want is to create a .bat file that, when opened, runs .cmd and allows me to input the video link (something like `youtube-dl <link> --format mp4` so that I could just input my link on `<link>`). 
Better than that, is that a way that this input could be extracted directly from my clipboard? So that, for example, if I wanted to download a certain video, I'd just open the .bat and it'd automatically replace `<link>` with whatever's on my clipboard. Best I could get so far is this:

```
@echo off
youtube-dl https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=ASJa8sa8adaAO0-A9Ddad9k --format mp4
pause
```

but this only downloads this specific playlist (although automatically, which is better than nothing haha)

Comment: There is a `clip` command to push something to the clipboard, but sadly MS didn't bother to give us something to *get* something *from* the clipboard. You have to google for an external tool (there are plenty of them). (if you are open to another language, Powershell has read/write access to the clipboard)

Comment: In your large description you didn't explained why the input must be taken from the clipboard. If you execute a `set /P` command, you may give as input the contents of the clipboard via a right-click and `paste` option...

Comment: because I want to be able to copy the video link and just double click the .bat file to download it

Answer (score 1):

check [***printClip.bat***](https://github.com/npocmaka/batch.scripts/blob/master/hybrids/mshta/printClip.bat)

you can do something like:

```
for /f "tokens=* delims=" %%# in ('printClip.bat') do set "supposingly_link=%%#"
echo %supposingly_link% | findstr /i "www.youtube.com youtu.be" >nul 2>&1 && (
   youtube-dl %supposingly_link% --format mp4
)
```